# Select2 Display Different Value after selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-select2

I am trying to find an updated answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393872/different-display-value-for-selecte-text-using-select2-js) as it seems that the formatSelection option for Select2 does no longer work, or is simply not working for me.

Basically, I have a multi-select Select2 menu and would like to have the option's **value** displayed after being selected rather than it being the text description. For instance, I have a list of provinces where each one has a shorthand as a value on the option (AB for Alberta, BC for British Columbia, etc.) **Those** are the ones I would like to have displayed after being selected. Is there a simple way of doing this in Select2 4.0.0?

Markup:

```
<select id="provSelect" multiple data-role="none" >

</select>
```

for the JS:

```
$("#provSelect").select2({
          width:"100%",
          formatSelection: formatSelection});
```

With the appropriate function:

```
function formatSelection(item){
         return item.id;
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't think there is much to show. I dynamically add items from a text file so my markup is empty. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select2 still has a formatting API, it's called **templating** now. Example:

```
function formatState (state) {
    if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
    var $state = $(
        '<span><img src="vendor/images/flags/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
    );
    return $state;
};

$(".js-example-templating").select2({
    templateSelection: formatState
});
```

You can template the result and selection differently; docs [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating).

Comment: I had to use the templateSelection option instead of templateResult for my purposes, but this achieved what I wanted :) thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Template Selections can be found here -> https://select2.org/selections or review the sample below:

```
    function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }

  var baseUrl = "/user/pages/images/flags";
  var $state = $(
    '<span><img class="img-flag" /> <span></span></span>'
  );

  // Use .text() instead of HTML string concatenation to avoid script injection issues
  $state.find("span").text(state.text);
  $state.find("img").attr("src", baseUrl + "/" + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + ".png");

  return $state;
};

$(".js-example-templating").select2({
  templateSelection: formatState
});
```