# How to set value to display instead of text in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

```js
$('select').select2({width:"300"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="convertIt" multiple>
    <option value="A">Australia</option>
    <option value="U">US </option>
    <option value="J">Japan</option>
    <option value="E">Europe</option>
    <option value="C">Canada</option>
  </select>
```

I also tried with `id` but not worked

```
$('#convertIt').select2({
    placeholder: "Select an country"
}).select2("data",
     [{"id":"test1","text":"Henry Ford"},{"id":"test2","text":"Tom Phillips"}]
);
```

Thanks

Comment: display in the search pane or display when an option is selected?

Comment: when an option is selected, it would be `A` or `U` and in dropdown it would be `Australia` or `US` will display.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different display value for selecte text using select2.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393872/different-display-value-for-selecte-text-using-select2-js)

Comment: @OmasuPlus : can you please update my live demo with duplicate question that you maked ?

Comment: have you tried the answers from the given duplicate link? i tried one fiddle there and it solves/answers your question...

Comment: Yes its working thanks a lot

Comment: yea use templateSelection... i was trying to create an answer but cant post cause of SO's strict answer rules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function formatSelection(val) {return val.id;}

$('select').select2({templateSelection: formatSelection,width:"300"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="convertIt" multiple>
    <option value="A">Australia</option>
    <option value="U">US </option>
    <option value="J">Japan</option>
    <option value="E">Europe</option>
    <option value="C">Canada</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function formatSelection(val) {
  return val.id;
}

$('#convertIt').select2({
    placeholder: "Select an country",
    formatSelection: formatSelection,
}).select2("data",
     [{"id":"test1","text":"Henry Ford"},{"id":"test2","text":"Tom Phillips"}]
);
```